# How to define SQL fetch outside it's function?

Tags: sql, node.js

When I try to execute SQL result `console.log(row.plan);` or `this.row.plan`; outside of function, I get error:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'plan')`

This is how I fetched result `plan`:

```
var row;
var plan;
               MySQL.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'onyx'", (err, result) => {
               
               if(err) { console.log(`[!] SQL Error: ${err}`); return; }
               
               Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
                    row = result[key]   
                   console.log(row.plan)
                                  
               });
 
           });
```

The problem is that when I try to use `console.log(row.plan);` outside of this `Object.keys...`function, I get an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'plan')`.

For example:

```
MySQL.query("SELECT 
...
               Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
                    row = result[key]   
                  
               });
 console.log(row.plan) // HERE
           });
console.log(row.plan) // OR HERE
```

I defined `row` and `plan` outside with `var`. I am new to JavaScript so I am not sure what to use. I tried with `let` and `const` but both gives the same error.

I use node V16.15.1

Comment: Why closed immediately? I still didn't get the answer i am looking for...

Comment: Waited 1.5h to post new question with better explanation and I noted that I tried what i've been told to...